# What's the JavaScript syntax to cast and destructure a param?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring, object-destructuring

This seems like a stupid question. Say I have a function which accepts an object. How can I cast that object as `props`, but also destructure `props.id` to `id` (in the parameter declaration)?

```js
function go ({ id }) {
  const props = arguments[0]; // how to do this with destructure?
  console.log('props', props, 'id', id);
}

go({id: 2});
```

Comment: You cannot. Keep `props` as an argument then `const { id } = props;`

Comment: Your code works when I try it.

Comment: Zerkms has the best answer, but if you don't care about code quality and you know the `go` function won't receive extra parameters, you can do `function go(props, {id}=props)`

Comment: @KhauriMcClain that's a dirty hack but I genuinely like it! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do it - just keep `props` as an argument as well to make this code simpler and easier to read:

```js
function go (props) {
  const { id } = props;
  console.log('props', props, 'id', id);
}

go({id: 2});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can follow this approach which names a param as props and destructures that param to extract the value of Id.

*The problem comes when you need to pass an additional param.*

```js
function go (props, {id} = props) {
  //const props = arguments[0]; // how to do this with destructure?
  console.log('props', props, 'id', id);
}

go({id: 2});
```

Comment: even worse problem would come if a caller passes the second parameter accidentally